# Copy sql statement using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, t-sql

I am trying to past copied id's between brackets of an sql statement - final goal is to have the full sql statement with id's in the clipboard.
My current approach is:

> 1) loop over the id's untill the last row and add "," for each id unless it is the last one.
>
> > 2) past the formated Ids with "," to "Sql Format" sheet & copy result to clipboard

NOTE: I don't realy want to past the Id's to a sheet, if it is possible to skip it somehow it would be awesome but not a must.

How / where do I store the Sql statement and tell the macro past the copied id's between the brackets and then copy the whole updated statement?

**VBA:**

```
Sub QueryFormat()
  Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim OracleQuery As String

    Set ws = Sheets("File") 'from here I copy the Id's
    Set sq = Sheets("Sql format") 'past here the Id's with ","
    Set fl = Sheets("main") ' here is my button for macro


    Lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With ws
        For i = 2 To Lastrow
            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then _
            sq.Range("A" & i).Formula = .Range("A" & i) & ","
        If i = Lastrow Then _
        sq.Range("A" & i).Formula = .Range("A" & i)
        Next i
        sq.Range("A1:A" & i).Copy
      'Copy to clipboard the required format for the SQL query
    End With
```

SQL statement:

```
SELECT x.PERSON_ID,
       x.FULL_NAME,
       x.CURRENT_EMPLOYEE_FLAG,
       (SELECT xxx.full_name
          FROM per_people_x xxx
         WHERE xxx.PERSON_ID = xx.SUPERVISOR_ID) SUPERVISOR,
       (SELECT ppos.actual_termination_date
          FROM per_periods_of_service ppos
         WHERE ppos.period_of_service_id = xx.period_of_service_id
           AND ppos.actual_termination_date < trunc(SYSDATE)) Termination_Date,
       (SELECT trunc(ppos.last_update_date)
          FROM per_periods_of_service ppos
         WHERE ppos.period_of_service_id = xx.period_of_service_id
           AND ppos.actual_termination_date < trunc(SYSDATE)) Last_Update_Date
  FROM per_people_x x, per_all_assignments_f xx
WHERE x.PERSON_ID IN ()
   AND x.PERSON_ID = xx.PERSON_ID
   AND xx.PRIMARY_FLAG = 'Y'
   AND xx.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE = 'E'
   AND xx.effective_start_date =
       (SELECT MAX(f.effective_start_date)
          FROM per_all_assignments_f f
         WHERE f.person_id = xx.person_id
           AND f.primary_flag = 'Y'
           AND f.assignment_type = 'E')
```

the Id's need to go between the brackets:

> WHERE x.PERSON_ID IN ()

Regards,
Slava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After constantly bleeding from my eyes trying to solve this, I finaly found a solution to:
1) Copy + past Id's from Sheet1 to (Sheet2,(A2)) adding "," for each row besides the last one (So the SQL query will work);
2)Store In Sheet2(A1) The first part of the query - Must be one line no spaces, and text format
3)Find the last row with Id and past the second part of the SQL query;
4) Copy range in Sheet2 A1:A(Lastrow) to cliboard to be ready to use.

```
    Sub PlSqlQueryFormat()

        Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim OracleQuery As String


        Set ws = Sheets("File") 'Source with plain Id's
        Set sq = Sheets("Sql format") 'Destination to past the Adjusted Id's
        Set fl = Sheets("main") 'My main UI with buttons & Instructions


        Lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With ws
            For i = 2 To Lastrow 'It starts with 2 because I don't want to start from header in A1
                If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then _
                sq.Range("A" & i).Formula = .Range("A" & i) & "," 'If there is Value AKA ID, add ","
            If i = Lastrow Then _
            sq.Range("A" & i).Formula = .Range("A" & i) 'If the ID is the last raw DONT add "," - just copy as is
            Next i

          'Copy to clipboard the required format for the SQL query
          Dim Ne As Long
       Ne = sq.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'searching for last row to past the second part of the query after the last ID
       sq.Cells(Ne, "A").Value = sq.Range("B1").Value ' B1=Second part of the query

        sq.Range("A1:A" & i).Copy ' copy the whole range with the Query and the Id's inside the query

        End With
        MsgBox "PlSql Query was successfully copied "

      '  fl.Range("D7") = "Done" 'Message text in cel AFTER: 1)Format is made & 2)Copied to clipboard
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Hope it will help someone with similar task in the future.

Regards,
Slava

Answer (score 0):

Storing the IDs in a Table will make it easy to refer to them

> ```
>   Range("Table1[ID]")
> ```

[image]

[image]

You can then either use `VBA.Join()` or `WorksheetFunction.TextJoin()` to wrap the IDs.

> ```
>   Chr(34) & Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose( Range("Table1[ID]") ), Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34)) & Chr(34)
>
>   Chr(34) & WorksheetFunction.TextJoin( Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34),True, Range("Table1[ID]")) & Chr(34)
> ```

Comment: Hi TinMan, I am not sure how to  approach to your method. I am new to vba so not even sure how to use your advise. could you please ellaborate or walk me through step by step?

Comment: Not much time.  If you convert your range to a table you can refer to the ID like this `Range( Table_Name[Coulmn_Name])`. Alternately, you can replace `Range("Table1[ID]")` with any 1D range in the code above.

Comment: Tried in different ways, but lack of a sharp eye to details and lack of expirience are stoping me from moving forward. still looking for guidence. Meanwhile I will keep trying untill my eyes bleed, but hope overcome this issue before then :).